# Decimal to binary conversion of integer in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal, dev-c++

I have this short code which generally (in 99% of the time) works fine for converting integers from decimal to binary system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int numDec, remainder=0, numBin=0;
    printf ("Provide an integer you want to convert!\n\n");
    scanf ("%d", &numDec);
    printf ("\n");
    while (numDec>0)
    {
        numBin+= numDec % 2 * pow (10, remainder);
        numDec = numDec / 2;
        remainder+= 1;
    }
    printf ("%d", numBin);
    return 0;
}
```

A problem emerges though if I use the compiler DevC++, but not in any other case.
And this weird issue is, that for some inputs like 210 I get a wrong answer.
Instead of the desired **11010010** I get **11010009**. I am not sure why this is occuring or what could be in the background causing this. I'd really like to know what is going on in DevC++ that inflicts it. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `DevC++` has a bad `pow` implementation. Stop using it. `pow` is a floating-point function. Rewrite your code to use only integer arithmetic.

Comment: Also, do not encode binary as decimals. Just write out the binary digits one by one or store them as binary in an integer type or as “0” and “1” characters in a string.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up going with  `numBin+= numDec % 2 * round (pow (10, remainder));` Is it safe to stick to it on the long run?

Comment: No.  Stop using `pow()`.  You are not doing floating point arithmetic in scientific calculations; it is inappropriate for use in integer arithmetic.

Comment: When you write `numDec % 2 * round (pow (10, remainder))`, you are thinking of writing a binary numeral as a string of decimal digits, as if the binary 101 were one hundred and one. It is not. Stop trying to use decimal notation to think about or represent binary. You know what we use for binary? Binary. Once the user’s input is scanned into an `int` with `scanf("%d", …)`, it is already in binary. The `int` objects are encoded using binary. They have bits in them. Use those bits. `scanf` converted the user’s decimal to binary. The job is done.

Comment: All you need to do is write out the binary digits. The only hard part here is finding the first one to write out, due to the order we write numerals. Here is some code to find the first bit set in a number, if the number is not too big: `unsigned bit = 1; while (2*bit <= number) bit *= 2;`. Then you can write the bits with `while (bit) { if (number & bit) putchar('1'); else putchar('0'); bit /= 2; } putchar('\n');`. Try that code, then find ways to modify it to make it better.

Comment: @IstvánCsige Instead of `* pow (10, remainder);`, use `* pow10`.  It is `int pow10 = 1` at first.  Then scale it by 10 each time at the end of the loop.

Comment: I would cast the value to an unsigned of the same width. On a 2's complement architecture (i.e., everything), the bit pattern is preserved. Mask each bit from msb to lsb and place an ASCII `1` or `0` in a `char` buffer of size: `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1`, so there's room for a nul-terminator: `\0`. Then simply use: `printf("%s", buf)`. When that's working, you can look at skipping leading zero bits in the C string if that's the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As noted by [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil), my first answer contains quite a few of undefined behavior. I'll leave that answer below for reference.

Here you are a fixed answer:

```cpp
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t get_uint_binary_rep(unsigned i, char (*rep)[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned) + 1])
{
    char* it = *rep;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        *it++ = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        /* Skip leading zeros */
        unsigned digitCount = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned);
        unsigned const mask = (unsigned)1 << (digitCount - 1);
        while ((i & mask) == 0)
        {
            i <<= 1;
            --digitCount;
        }
    
        while (digitCount != 0)
        {
            *it++ = '0' + ((i & mask) != 0);
            i <<= 1;
            --digitCount;
        }
    }

    *it = '\0';
    return (it - *rep);
}

size_t get_int_binary_rep(int i, char (*rep)[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 2])
{
    size_t charCount = 0;
    unsigned u = 0;
    char* it = *rep;
    if (i < 0)
    {
        if (i == INT_MIN)
        {
            u = INT_MAX;
            ++u;
        }
        else
        {
            u = -i;
        }

        *it++ = '-';
        charCount = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        u = i;
    }

    char urep [CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned) + 1] = {0};
    size_t const urepCharCount = get_uint_binary_rep(u, &urep);
    strncpy(it, urep, urepCharCount + 1);
    return charCount + urepCharCount;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char rep[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 2] = {0};

    get_int_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = -5;
    get_int_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = 10;
    get_int_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = 210;
    get_int_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = INT_MAX;
    get_int_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = INT_MIN;
    get_int_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);
}
```

---

How about evaluating the binary representation of an `int` like this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void get_binary_rep(int i, char (*rep)[8 * sizeof(int) + 1])
{
    char* it = *rep;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        *it++ = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        if (i < 0)
        {
            *it++ = '-';
            i = -i;
        }
    
        /* Skip leading zeros */
        int digitCount = 8 * sizeof(int);
        int const mask = 1 << (digitCount - 1);
        while ((i & mask) == 0)
        {
            i <<= 1;
            --digitCount;
        }
    
        while (digitCount != 0)
        {
            char const ch = (i & mask) ? '1' : '0';
            *it++ = ch;
            i <<= 1;
            --digitCount;
        }
    }

    *it = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char rep[8 * sizeof(int) + 1] = {0};

    get_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = -5;
    get_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = 10;
    get_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = 210;
    get_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep)

    i = INT_MAX;
    get_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);

    i = INT_MIN;
    get_binary_rep(i, &rep);
    printf("%d(10) = %s(2)\n", i, rep);
}
```

This version:

1. Does not assume `i` is positive;
2. Does not rely on `pow`;
3. Can convert integers from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`.

Output:

```
0(10) = 0(2)
-5(10) = -101(2)
10(10) = 1010(2)
210(10) = 11010010(2)
2147483647(10) = 1111111111111111111111111111111(2)
-2147483648(10) = -10000000000000000000000000000000(2)
```

**Note:** I pass parameter `rep` as a pointer to a `char[33]` in order to retain the information about the size.
In a first version of `get_binary_rep` I was `memset`ting all the bytes in the buffer to `'\0'`:

```c
static size_t const rep_size = sizeof(*rep) / sizeof((*rep)[0]);
memset(*rep, 0, rep_size);
```

Still, even without a call to `memset`, I think passing `rep` as a pointer may be useful as the compiler will warn you if you pass a pointer to a buffer with a different size.

Comment: `i = -i;` overflows (and so the behavior is not defined by the C standard) when `i` is `INT_MIN` and two’s complement is in use. `1 << (digitCount - 1)` overflows. `i <<= 1` overflows whenever it would shift a 1 bit into the high position.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int)` is more portable than `8 * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. Also, when `i` is `INT_MIN` I have a buffer overflow, as I write `'\0'` to `(*rep)[33]`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to convert from binary to decimal, since computers only use one system - binary. This can then be represented to human users in other forms such as decimal or hex. Therefore it probably makes far more sense to convert from an integer to a string with decimal format.

Whereas formats such as "converting" some binary like 1000 (8 dec) to a similar-looking decimal number 1000 (one thousand) is unlikely a useful format for any purpose. Similarly, an array of ones and zeroes is unlikely useful. BCD might have some uses, but that's not what you are asking for.

Assuming you simply wish to display a binary number to a human user, then a string conversion is what makes most sense. Here is a simple example using 8 bit numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void get_binstr (char dst[8+1], uint8_t val) // 8 char + 1 null term
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)                  // iterate over 8 bits
  {
    size_t index = 8 - 1 - i;                // bit and array index, down counting from 7 to 0
    uint8_t bit = (val >> index) & 1;        // mask out the relevant bit
    dst[index] = bit + '0';                  // convert to string symbol value 
  }
  dst[8]='\0';                               // null terminate
}

int main (void)
{
  char str[8+1];
  get_binstr(str, 210);
  puts(str);
}
```